# need to make a div scale and scrollable on hover using css without javascript

Tags: css

We are building a product builder using an app that only allows us to change the css and nothing else. Need the preview image inside the div to magnify on hover and be scrollable from corner to corner in order to show the customers all the details on the product. I have already added css to make it scale up on hover but cant get it to scroll. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
.shappify_product_builder .option_image .spritespin-stage {
    width: 500px !important;
    height: 500px !important;
    background-size: 100% !important;
    margin-left: 40px;
}
.spritespin-stage { transition: all .2s ease-in-out; }
.spritespin-stage:hover { transform: scale(2); overflow: auto; }
```

and below is the html. I need the image in the div with .spritespin stage to magnify and be scrollable.

```html
<div id="option_image" class="rotationViewer option_image spritespin-instance" style="max-height: 544px; -webkit-user-select: none; overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 3600px; height: 3600px;" unselectable="on">
    <div class="spritespin-stage" style="width: 3600px; height: 3600px; top: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute; display: block; background-image: url(&quot;//www.shappify-cdn.com/images/78432/86058914/001_first-screen.png&quot;); background-size: 500px 500px; background-position: 0px 0px; background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div>
    <div class="spritespin-preload" style="width: 3600px; height: 3600px; top: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute; display: none;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have the html for this example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if below example helps to solve the problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/6wy87p8e/2/

```css
.spritespin-stage {
width: 100px !important;
height: 100px !important;
background-size: 100% !important;
background-color:red;
transition: all .2s ease-in-out; 
transform: scale(1);
margin:0;
}
.option_image{overflow:hidden; width:100px;height:100px}
.option_image:hover{overflow:scroll;}
.option_image:hover .spritespin-stage{margin:50px 0 0 50px;transform: scale(2);}


css css3
```

```html
<div class="shappify_product_builder">
  <div class="option_image">
  <p class="spritespin-stage">Test content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Manivannan. The code works here when I run it but it doesnt work on the app i am working with. I am attaching the html from the dev tools with the question above. maybe it'll give you a better idea of the structure of the page.

Comment: Pls add the code in any code snipet jsfiddle or stackoverflow native code snipet to debug

Comment: I added the html for this div above. the div and the image are 500x500px when they load and we want to enlarge them on hover inside the 500x500px div and be able to scroll around to see the detail.

Comment: see video of how the page is set up, how it zooms but the entire page scrolls instead of just the image. [link] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/gamlib8ptauajo8/code%20and%20preview.mov?dl=0)

Comment: It works now. All I had to do was add !important to overflow: scroll. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The parent div containing `.spritespin-stage:hover` needs to have `overflow: auto`.  The parent also needs a fixed width and height, so when the div inside zooms in, the scroll bars spawn instead of growing with `.spritespin-stage`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply ms-nitrogen. The code works here when I run it but it doesnt work on the app i am working with. I am attaching the html above with the question. maybe it'll give you a better idea of the structure of the page.

Comment: I added the html for this div above. the div and the image are 500x500px when they load and we want to enlarge them on hover inside the 500x500px div and be able to scroll around to see the detail. see video of how the page is set up, how it zooms but the entire page scrolls instead of just the image. [link] (dropbox.com/s/gamlib8ptauajo8/code%20and%20preview.mov?dl=0‌​)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div id="option_image" class="rotationViewer option_image spritespin-instance" style="max-height: 544px; -webkit-user-select: none; overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 3600px; height: 3600px;" unselectable="on">
    <div class="spritespin-stage" style="width: 3600px; height: 3600px; top: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute; display: block; background-image: url(&quot;//www.shappify-cdn.com/images/78432/86058914/001_first-screen.png&quot;); background-size: 500px 500px; background-position: 0px 0px; background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div>
    <div class="spritespin-preload" style="width: 3600px; height: 3600px; top: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute; display: none;"></div>
</div>
```